# SIGSEGV handler using Python with C extension modules

Tags: python, c, signals, cpython, extending

I'm trying to setup a SIGSEGV signal handler for Python using a C extension module:

```py
import my_extension_module
import ctypes

my_extension_module.setup_segfault_handler()
ctypes.string_at(0) # i would like this to error and not segfault
```

I've seen several questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705792/c-sigsegv-handler-mprotect) and functions like `longjmp` or `setjmp`, but none of these seem to work how I intend.

I **am aware** that not terminating after a SIGSEGV is a bad idea for a number of reasons, but I need it nonetheless.

Here is my current code:

```c
static jmp_buf buf;

void handle(int signum) {
  PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError, "segmentation fault occured");
  longjmp(buf, 1);
}

static PyObject* method_setup() {
  signal(SIGSEGV, handle);
  setjmp(buf);

  Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

Comment: This is fraught with danger.  I have no clue whether the Python interpreter will let you play games like this.  _Why_ do you need it?

Comment: Segmentation violations are often a symptom of memory corruption. So it's rarely possible to do anything useful in the event handler.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "number of reasons" that you need to do this?

Comment: You still haven't answered the question as to _why_ you _think_ you need this or _why_ you _think_ this will work? Even in pure C (where you have total control) , you can _not_ "recover" from this. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431879/c-handle-signal-sigfpe-and-continue-execution/39432614#39432614https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431879/c-handle-signal-sigfpe-and-continue-execution/39432614#39432614 as to why